# How to switch the 'action' field in an HTML form dynamically?

Tags: javascript, forms, action

I have a form like this:

```
<form id="form_directorio" name="form_directorio" onSubmit="cambiar_url(this);" method='post'>

3 options select...

<a href="#" class="button"
onclick="if(valida_directorio()) document.getElementById('form_directorio').submit(); else return false;"><?php echo $text_boton_form;?> <span>>></span></a>
</form>
```

and my function in javascript:

```
function cambiar_url() {

var provincia=document.getElementById(provincia).value;
var poblacion=document.getElementById(poblacion).value;
var aseguradora=document.getElementById(aseguradora).value;

// URL friendly
var URL_AMIGABLE="/Provincia:" +provincia+"/Ciudad:"+poblacion+"/Aseguradora:"+aseguradora+"/";

var url = 'http://fronesis.com/directorio/ver' + URL_AMIGABLE;

document.getElementById('form_directorio').action = url;

return true;
}
```

I would like have a dinamic action form.

And no work... what is wrong?

Comment: It might not work in some browsers, which browsers did you test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "onsubmit" event is triggered only when you submit "normally" the form, never when you submit it yourself via JavaScript, so

> `onSubmit="cambiar_url(this);"`

tells the browser to invoke `cambiar_url(this)` whenever you submit the form by click on an `input[type=submit]` button (or typing ENTER key in a `input[type=text]`, but it won't be invoked with

```
document.getElementById('form_directorio').submit()
```

So you should try :

```
<form id="form_directorio" name="form_directorio" onSubmit="cambiar_url(this);" method='post'>

3 options select...

<a href="#" class="button"
onclick="if(valida_directorio()) { var myForm = document.getElementById('form_directorio'); cambiar_url(myForm); myForm.submit();} else return false;"><?php echo $text_boton_form;?> <span>>></span></a>
</form>
```

N.B. : the use of 'onsubmit' and 'onclick' is bad practice, see for example http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/unobtrusive-javascript-important or http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: i´m trying changing my buttom with a imput submit and still no work. Your code neither work.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! i test your code and work. Now i know my problem is here: var provincia=document.getElementById(provincia).value;
  var poblacion=document.getElementById(poblacion).value;
  var aseguradora=document.getElementById(aseguradora).value;

  // Generando la URL Amigable.
  var URL_AMIGABLE="/Provincia:" +provincia+"/Ciudad:"+poblacion+"/Aseguradora:"+aseguradora+"/"; when i try to make the full url.

Comment: Here is my problem: provincia=document.getElementById(provincia).value; How i can have the value of a selected element?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `cambiar_url` should return false or you can use `event.preventDefault()` .